# Set Azure function appsettings via PowerShell removes special characters

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, az

I use an Azure function and set the environment variables via PowerShell with the command: 
`az functionapp config appsettings set --resource-group $myResourceGroup --name $myAzureFunction --settings @appSettingsAsArray`.

This works well until special characters e.g are in a secret.

I debugged my PowerShell script and all signs are processed correctly from the script and the execution of the command to set the appsettings was successful too.

If I open the Azure Portal and have a look about the appsettings of the Azure function I can see the secret/value is different to the secret/value which was set by the PowerShell script.

So it looks like during the command Azure replaces/removes special characters like: '**^**', '**`**'.

I tried it with such a secret: like => **'=P^1tUbdw_G`Ci'I6T°10~rhlQR'** and the secret in the function is: => **'=P1tUbdw_GCi'I6T°10~rhlQR'**.

In this case the signs '**^**', '**`**' are being removed.

In case the secret/value has an '**&**' character Azure will cut everything afterwards.

Any ideas what I can do about this to use a secret/value with such signs? I know one option would be to use another secret, but it would be beneficial to know how I can handle it with such signs in a value.

Answer (score 1):

Backtick and caret are special signs in powershell, so they should be escaped with another backtick.

```
=P`^1tUbdw_G``Ci'I6T°10~rhlQR
```